# SQL - Conditional Left Join Count Performance is Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, left-join

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have three tables. Builders, Addresses and BuilderAddresses.

I have the following query which is used to give me my total count of records during paging:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Builders
LEFT JOIN Addresses ON Addresses.AddressId IN 
(SELECT AddressId FROM BuilderAddresses WHERE  BuilderId = Builders.BuilderId AND IsPrimary = 1)
WHERE Builders.[Email] LIKE '%TEST'%
ORDER BY Builders.[Name]
```

This query is particularly slow when records in the table approach 100k+. Does any one have any suggestions on how to get this query to **execute faster**??

On a table with 120K records, it take 452ms to get the count. When it comes to returning the records used in the paging, say 100 rows, it takes 11ms. I would really like to improve this if I can.

If I need to add greater detail, please let me know and I will edit the question.

Comment: share a fiddle. and mention if there is/are index created on tables

Comment: Good idea. But Filipe was too quick. Next time for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is not necessary for the `COUNT`, and you can remove that `IN` validation by joining with `BuilderAdresses` directly.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Builders b
LEFT JOIN BuilderAddresses ba ON ba.BuilderId = b.BuilderId AND isPrimary = 1
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON a.AddressId = ba.AddressId
WHERE Builders.[Email] LIKE '%TEST' %
```

Comment: Perfect. That works as expected with the speed required. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely to be with using `IN` as part of the join predicate. What it looks like you need to do is first join the junction table `BuilderAddresses` and then join `Addresses`, so something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Builders
JOIN BuilderAddresses ON BuilderAddresses.BuilderId = Builders.BuilderId AND isPrimary = 1
JOIN Addresses ON Addresses.AddressId = BuilderAddresses.AddressId
WHERE Builders.[Email] LIKE '%TEST%'
ORDER BY Builders.[Name]
```

Comment: Thanks. But the IsPrimary is a necessary condition of the result set. It cannot be removed.